# Running Map-Reduce job on specific files/blocks in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, indexing, hdfs

First off, I'm new to hadoop :)

I have a large data set of gzipped files (TBs of documents in gzipped files around the size of 100-500mb each).

Basically, I need some sort of filtering of my input to my map-reduce jobs.

I want to analyze these files in various ways. Many of these jobs only need to analyze files of a certain format (of certain length, containing certain words etc - all sorts of arbitrary (inverted) indexes), and it takes unreasonably long to process the entire dataset for each job. So I want to create indexes that points to specific blocks/files in HDFS.

I can generate the required indices manually, but how do I specify exactly which (thousands of) specific files/blocks I want to process as input to mappers? Can I do this without reading the source data into e.g. HBase? Do I want to? Or am I tackling this problem completely wrong?

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, you're looking for a way to process just a subset of the files in an input path?  How are you initiating jobs, programmatically?

Comment: How would targeting HDFS blocks instead of running different jobs for different formats(files) make you task faster? Can you elaborate your question more?

Comment: Sorry for being so vague. I do not yet feel at home in the hadoop stack, so I know my terminology and way of thinking is slightly off. The following example might help explain what I'm trying to achieve: Given 1,000,000 files, and an index telling my exactly which 5,000 files contains the word *sunshine*, run a map-reduce job that analyzes all documents containing the words *sunshine*.

Comment: I should probably add that I have a plethora of indices that all overlap, so I'm trying to avoid have duplicates of files in the ./docs_containting_sunshine folder and in the ./docs_containing_rainy folder, which would otherwise (obviously) make it easy to process the limited subset of relevant documents.

Comment: Oh, and I've got no restrictions on how to initiate jobs. Whatever makes this possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have some way by which you can know which x files to process in a large corpus of files, you can use the `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.setInputPathFilter(Job, Class<? extends PathFilter>)` method when configuring your job.

You'll need to pass an class that implements `PathFilter`. Hadoop will create a new instance of this class and it will be presented which each file in the corpus via the `boolean accept(Path path)` method. You can then use this to filter down the files to actual process map tasks against (whether that be based upon the filename, size, last modified timestamp etc).

To target specific blocks, you'll need to implement your own extension of FileInputFormat, specifically overriding the `getSplits` method. This method uses the `listStatus` method to determine what the input files are to process (and is where the previously mentioned PathFilter is invoked), after which it then determines how to break up those files into splits (if the files are splittable). So in this `getSplits` method you'll again need to use your reference data to target the specific splits you're interested in.

As for storing / retrieving this target file and splits information, you have several choices of persistence store such as a Key / Value store (HBase, as you noted in your question), a separate Database (MySQL, etc), an inverted index (Lucene) etc.

Answer (score 2):

Because you'd like to filter input based on the file content (file containing the word *foobar*) and not file metadata (file name / size, etc.) you would actually need the kind of indexes I created based on Hadoop InputSplit. See [my blog](http://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/05/24/indexing-on-mapreduce-2/)

Comment: Cool. I've since asking this question actually built a similar setup. I'm glad you've added benchmarks, I'll try and compare my slightly different approach to yours. Do you have a rough example of what your data looks like, so I can generate something similar to benchmark on?

Answer (score 1):

Running Map-Reduce job on specific files in HDFS means filter out the input file based on some criteria. [Here](http://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/07/29/hadoop-filter-input-files-used-for-mapreduce/) is a good blog posted by Antoine Amend, will be helpful.